# Jade. How to write from new line?

Tags: html, pug

I'm writing on jade in Visual Code the code below

```
div
h1 Ocean
ul
    li Comedy
    li his
p.
    Hello
```

Get

```
<div><h1>Ocean</h1><ul><li>Comedy</li><li>his</li></ul><p>Hello       </p></div>
```

Expecting

```
<div>
     <h1>Ocean</h1>
     <ul>
         <li>Comedy</li>
         <li>his</li>
     </ul>
     <p>Hello</p></div>
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I want that each tag start from a new line

Comment: But it doesnt matter... the output is the same...

Comment: [`options: { pretty:true; }`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jade#pretty)?

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting the output to be indented, just set that option in your grunt file:

```
options: {
    pretty: true
}
```

[See the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jade#pretty)

Edit: As @nycynik pointed out, jade is now pug, but the same option may be used: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-pug#pretty